# Redux-Persist Secure Encryption

Tags: react-native, encryption, asyncstorage, redux-persist

i am trying to learn how to securely save my redux state in my react-native app.

i am using redux-persist-transform-encrypt as per the documentation: https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt'

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: 'my-super-secret-key'
})

const reducer = persistReducer(
  {
    transforms: [encryptor]
  },
  baseReducer
)
```

but i dont not how to securely set the `secretKey` string `'my-super-secret-key'`?

when the js is compiled, wouldn't the value of the string be visible in the bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the **keys** would be visible in the **`JS bundle`**.To overcome this problem you need to either set *`nested persisted states`*, in the `redux-persist` and store the keys to a **`secured-db`** or **`keystore`** in some way or use this package as mentioned [here](https://github.com/CodingZeal/redux-persist-sensitive-storage).

```
const mainPersistConfig = {
  key: "main",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ["yourKeyReducer"]
};

const tokenPersistConfig = {
  key: "token",
  storage: sensitiveStorage
};
```

Since it provides with [**`creation of the sensitive storage`**](https://github.com/CodingZeal/redux-persist-sensitive-storage/issues/5), the security issue is overcome.

Comment: For the sensitive storage, you could use the following module:  https://github.com/chaudhryjunaid/redux-persist-encrypted-async-storage